# google_accounts_daemon[1140]: Full path required for exclude: net[4026532634]

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, centos7, systemd

I issued the command journalctl -xe on my VM Centos7 in Google Cloud and I got this error:

```
google_accounts_daemon[1140]: Full path required for exclude: net[4026532634]
```

Does anyone have an idea on this?

Comment: Are you running Docker on this instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response to the bug report I filed on Google Cloud Platform:

> The accounts daemon is activated every ~90 seconds to ensure that expired SSH keys are removed from the guest. At that time, the guest will attempt to create/update/remove users based on the non-expired keys in metadata. If some user isn't getting set up properly (maybe there is a problem adding the user to one of the listed groups?) it might result in something getting called every couple minutes.

[Google Cloud Platform Issue #444](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/issues/444#issuecomment-337365382)

I did not take more time to debug the issue, since the only problem is the volume of log messages.

The log messages stopped when I upgraded the instances to CentOS 7.4.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I am running a docker inside my VM. ^_^